# React setState изменение состояния по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, setstate

Имеется код:

```
 const STATbJI = [
    {
        id: 1,
        textName: 'breaking news1',
        text:'lorem ipsum1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        textName: 'breaking news2',
        text:'lorem ipsum2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        textName: 'breaking news3',
        text:'lorem ipsum3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        textName: 'breaking news4',
        text:'lorem ipsum4'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        textName: 'breaking news5',
        text:'lorem ipsum5'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        textName: 'breaking news6',
        text:'lorem ipsum6'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        textName: 'breaking news7',
        text:'lorem ipsum7'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        textName: 'breaking news8',
        text:'lorem ipsum8'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        textName: 'breaking news9',
        text:'lorem ipsum9'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        textName: 'breaking news10',
        text:'lorem ipsum10'
    }
];

const News = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            isShow: true
        };
    },
    render() {
        const { name, text } = this.props;
        const {isShow} = this.state;
        return (
                <div className="col">
                    { isShow ?
                        (<div className="card">
                            <h2>{name}</h2>
                            <p>{text}</p>
                        </div>)
                        : null}
                </div>
                );
            }
});
const NewsList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            novosti: STATbJI
        }
    },
    addnews(){
        this.setState  ({
            isShow: !this.state.isShow,
        });
        console.log('click')
    },
    render() {
        const { novosti } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="list">
                    {
                        novosti.map(novostb => (
                    <News
                        key={novostb.id}
                        name={novostb.textName}
                        text={novostb.text}
                     />
                    ))
                        }
                    <button className="addnews" onClick={this.addnews}>Добавить ещё новостb</button>
                </div>
            </div>
                );
            }
});

ReactDOM.render(
<NewsList />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Прошу тапками сильно не пинать) возможно вопрос ооочень глупый) Только недавно, относительно *"правильно"* начал изучать React.

Задача. На начальном экране должно отображаться две новости и по нажатию на кнопку добавлять ещё по две новости.

Застрял на моменте что бы хоть просто менять всем элементам состояние. Не понимаю почему по нажатию на кнопку у элементов оно не меняется. Как это исправить?
Где ошибки? и как это можно более лучше реализовать?
Есть ли возможность в самом массиве указать состояние? Или более верно через 
`getInitialState` ??
Спасибо

Comment: использую react 15.4
и  babel-core@5.8.38

Comment: перелезай на 16.X

Comment: На мой взгляд, в `state` у `NewsList` должен храниться массив отображаемых новостей. В таком случае не будет необходимости в `isShow` в `News` (который, кстати, у вас никак не меняется, а `isShow` из `NewsList` на него никак не влияет), а в `setState` при нажатии на кнопку достаточно будет обновлять список новостей

Comment: И не по вопросу: `novosti`, `novostb` и особенно `STATbJI` - это плохие названия переменных

Comment: Я с Вами полностью согласен, использую только для себя пока учусь, что бы было проще ориентироваться. Согласен что лучше изначально учить правильно описывать имена переменных. Но пока так легче заходит)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил небольшой хак - хранить в стейте количество отображаемых новостей. В самом начале их будет две, поэтому `count: 2`, а также, для обрезки массива использовать метод [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) - данный метод не изменяет исходный массив, а просто возвращает его часть, что нас устраивает, так как если бы он менялся, появилась бы мутация и непредвиденное поведение.

```
const NewsList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { 
      novosti: STATbJI,
      count: 2,
    }
  }
  addnews() {
    const { novosti, count } = this.state;
    if (count <== novosti.length - 2) {
      const newCount = count + 2;
      this.setState({ count: newCount });  
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { novosti, count } = this.state;
    return (
      <div >
        <div className = "list">
        {
          novosti.slice(0, count).map(novostb => (
            <News
              key = {novostb.id}
              name = {novostb.textName}
              text = {novostb.text} 
            />
          ))
        }
        <button className = "addnews" onClick = {this.addnews}>
          Добавить ещё новости
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

При клике на кнопку - меняем только количество видимых новостей, смена стейта вызовет ререндеринг компонента и отобразится новое количество новостей.

> И не по вопросу: `novosti`, `novostb` и особенно `STATbJI` - это плохие
>   названия переменных (справедливый комментарий от [@Regent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183458/regent))

Comment: Денис, огромное вам спасибо что подсказала и рассказали.
Огромное спасибо что сказали за слайс, действительно это очень крутая идея)
Все замечательно работает)
единственное ,в месте 
      if (count <== novosti.length - 2)
работает только с одним знаком равно.
Странно, а почему так? один знак равенства это ведь присваивание?
И сам оператор if. Его в реакте можно использовать?

Денис, ещё раз огромное спасибо что уделили время и все подробно рассказали!)

Comment: @ААльбертович по поводу оператора сравнения советую почитать вот тут: [Операторы сравнения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) просто в двух словах не поясню, есть строгое и нестрогое сравнение. И сам оператор `if` можно использовать в React - это законно. Ну и не за что, рад помочь советом )

Comment: Ещё раз огромное спасибо Денис )